# Botframework v4 preserve dialogSet after deployment

Tags: node.js, typescript, chatbot, botframework

I'm using Microsoft bot framework v4. Its DialogSet is always kept in memory, and will vanish after a code rebuild (i.e deployment), so existing conversation that happens to be in a dialog just before the rebuild, will get an error after deployment is done (the needed dialog is not found).

```
export class DialogBot extends ActivityHandler {


  private readonly conversationState: BotState;
  private readonly userState: BotState;
  private readonly dialogState: StatePropertyAccessor<DialogState>;
  private readonly nlpProcessor: NlpProcessor;
  private readonly dialogSet: DialogSet;
  private readonly cacheService: CacheService;
  private readonly mainProcessor: MainProcessors;

  constructor(conversationState: BotState, userState: BotState) {
    super();
    this.conversationState = conversationState;
    this.userState = userState;
    this.dialogState = this.conversationState.createProperty<DialogState>(
      'DialogState'
    );
    this.dialogSet = new DialogSet(this.dialogState);
```

You can see the dialogSet is always initiated new after a deployment

```
this.dialogSet = new DialogSet(this.dialogState);
```

Although the dialogStack is persisted into dialogState, its dialogs array isn't

```
export class DialogSet {
    private readonly dialogs: { [id: string]: Dialog } = {};
    private readonly dialogState: StatePropertyAccessor<DialogState>;
    private _telemetryClient: BotTelemetryClient;
    private _version: string;
```

The dialogs array only lives in memory, which holds respective Dialog objects the stack refers to. Once you rebuild code, it's gone.

I tried to extend DialogSet class, and save its dialogs property to Blob storage, however, Blob is recording only json, and doesnt reconstruct the dialogs array properly (which holds all Dialog objects).

Anyone has a solution to preserve DialogSet state through deployment ? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: There seems to be some misunderstanding here, though I'm not sure exactly what. A dialog set is meant to be static and not related to state. A dialog set represents a set of dialogs that your bot can potentially begin, rather than the dialogs your bot has actually begun in a specific conversation. A dialog set should be the same every time your bot runs, and it should not change. A dialog *stack* stored in dialog *state* is the thing that changes based on specific conversations. Could you perhaps post some code that demonstrates what you're doing so we can see where the problem is?

Comment: My code is too long to post here, I can only explain my logic in pseudo code. However, are you absolutely sure that's how dialogSet works ? Since if you take a look at the add() implementation, there's a suffix appender right there. If there's one dialogSet for everything, it will never have to append a suffix, that's why i'm pretty sure dialogSet will keep growing during usage, not static.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that dialog sets are not supposed to grow during usage. It may be a good idea to familiarize yourself with the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-dialog). I can't look at the add() implementation because I don't know what SDK you're using because you haven't posted any code. Can you at least tell us what language your bot is written in?

Comment: I just added my dialogSet initiation. I'm using nodejs.

Comment: If that's the case, we will have to add all possible dialogs into dialogSet at the point of initiation ? I'm talking about resuming a dialog after deployment

Comment: @KyleDelaney just a friendly reminder since question was closed yesterday, im afraid you didnt know I did modify

Comment: Sorry to keep you waiting. Yes, you should always add all possible dialogs into the dialog set at the point of initiation. This is how all Bot Framework dialogs are supposed to work, and any bot that does not do this is broken. You can see this pattern in every official [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.core-bot/dialogs/mainDialog.js#L23-L29) (note that `ComponentDialog.addDialog` calls `DialogSet.add` internally). No dialog is ever called that wasn't added at the time of construction. This ensures that your bot works after restart.

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Yes @KyleDelaney, I added all dialogs to my dialogSet at construction and it's all working. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dialog set is meant to be static and not related to state. A dialog set represents a set of dialogs that your bot can potentially begin, rather than the dialogs your bot has actually begun in a specific conversation. A dialog set should be the same every time your bot runs, and it should not change. A dialog *stack* stored in dialog *state* is the thing that changes based on specific conversations.

You should always add all possible dialogs into the dialog set at the point of initiation. This is how all Bot Framework dialogs are supposed to work, and any bot that does not do this is broken. You can see this pattern in every official [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.core-bot/dialogs/mainDialog.js#L23-L29) (note that `ComponentDialog.addDialog` calls `DialogSet.add` internally). No dialog is ever called that wasn't added at the time of construction. This ensures that your bot works after restart.

Comment: I've marked your answer as accepted. Many thanks @Kyle